# how to configure hostfile and machine file for mpirun?

Tags: mpi, hosts

I have a machine with 2 cpu and 12 core totally.
In CentOS, /etc/hosts is written as follows.

- 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
- ::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6
  localhost6.localdomain6

In my QChem calculation, it searches machinefile but it was not made in the installation procedure.

Is hosts file right?
How should I write machinefiles for mpi run?

In trying machinefile of

- chi
- chi
- chi
- ...

it runs using only one process. "chi" is hostname of my machine.
In case of "make -j4", it runs 4 processors. How does it happen?